# 2-Proportion Z-Test

Tags: z-test

I want to compare, with 2-proportion Z-Test, the number of student visits to school nurse office in Q1 of 2015 to Q2 of 2015.

What do I use for sample size for Q1 and Q2 when it’s different each month because of new students or students who drop?

[image]

Comment: Express data as proportions (eg 0.025 for the first entry) and apply any type of 2-group test. Not sure what the problem is here...

Comment: Hi Katya.  I want to compare all of Q1 to Q2 with 2-proportion Z-Test.  What is the collective sample size for Q1 and Q2?

Comment: Is the answer to simply calculate weighted average?